# Compute $\int_{e^{it}}{1\over \sqrt{z}}dz$, $0\le t\le \pi$ with principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute $\int_{e^{it}}{1\over  \sqrt{z}}dz$, $0\le t\le \pi$ with respect to the principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$. First, I am not quite sure what the principal branch is because I haven't come by any references regarding $\sqrt {z}$ itself.

What I **have** come by so far is: $\int_{\gamma}{1\over \sqrt{z}}dz=\int_{0}^{\pi}{ie^{it}\over e^{it\over 2}}dt$.

Suppose I did express $\sqrt{z}$ as $e^{1\over 2}(\ln |z|+i\text{Arg}(z))$, how is it applicable in the RHS in the equation above. Should I express $\sqrt{z}$ with its branch representation before I deal with the curve?

Comment: IIRC the principal branch is given by $\sqrt{z} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\text{Log}(z)}$ where $\text{Log}(z) = \log|z| + i \text{Arg}(z)$ is the principal branch of the logarithm defined such that $\text{Arg}(z)$ lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$ (branch cut along the negative $x$-axis). In this case $\text{Arg}(e^{i t}) = t$ for all $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ so the integral is what you have put up. Just evaluate the integral you have put up and you are done.

Comment: Also note that (the principal branch of) $2 z^{1/2}$ is holomorphic/analytic on (the neighborhood of) $\gamma$, and its (complex) derivative is $z^{-1/2}$